# How to schedule job with a particular time as well as interval?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

Using python's schedule module how can I start a job at particular time and thereon it should be scheduled at regular intervals.

Suppose I want to schedule a task every 4 hours starting from 09:00 am.

`schedule.every(4).hours.at("09:00").do(task) # This doesn't work`

How to achieve the above?

Comment: It should be like `schedule.every(4).hour.at("9:00").do(task)`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Its giving this error: AssertionError: Use hours instead of hour

Comment: it should be `hours` and not `hour` `schedule.every(4).hours.at("9:00").do(task)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the inner schedule (every 4 hours) into a separate function which would be called by the main schedule (fixed time). The inner schedule function would be the one calling your job function.

Example -

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print "I am working" #your job function

def schedule_every_four_hours():
    job() #for the first job to run
    schedule.every(4).hour.do(job)
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(schedule_every_four_hours)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you would like to kill  the schedule based on your requirement read more here. [Check here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-run-a-job-only-once).

Comment: This will give the desired result on the first day but on the next day it will again schedule the job at 09:00 when there already a schedule running for it i.e. at next day 09:00 am the job will be executed twice.

Comment: the double execution can be stopped by adding "schedule.CancelJob" at the end of schedule_every_four_hours() method.

Comment: @siddhu619 Yeah. I added the link at the end to help you with this. It was not clear from the question whether it is a daily process (i.e. it would end at some point of the same day) or once started it would be called every four hours indefinitely. You can manipulate according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution will not work if there are multiple schedules, as the schedule.CancelJob will cancel the other schedules on the pipe, better to use clear tag

```
import schedule
from datetime import  datetime
import time
def task():
    print 'I am here...',datetime.now()

def schedule_every_four_hours(clear):
    if clear =='clear':
        schedule.every(2).seconds.do(task).tag('mytask1') #for the first job to runschedule.every(4).hour.at("9:00").do(task)
    else:
        schedule.every(5).seconds.do(task).tag('mytask2')  # for the second job to runschedule.every(4).hour.at("9:00").do(task)
    print clear
    schedule.clear(clear)

now = datetime.now()


times = str(now.hour+0)+ ":"+str(now.minute+1)

times1 = str(now.hour+0)+ ":"+str(now.minute+3)
schedule.every().day.at(times).do(schedule_every_four_hours,'clear').tag('clear')


schedule.every().day.at(times1).do(schedule_every_four_hours,'clear1').tag('clear1')



while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as add on - because I was searching for a solution for this:

- Start at a specific time
- Have an interval
- Exit at a specific time

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt 
    
def job():
    now = dt.now()
    dt_string =  now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print ("I am working " ,dt_string )#your job function
    
def schedule_every_four_hours():
    job() #for the first job to run
     
    schedule.every(2).minutes.until("09:46").do(job)
        
    
    print(' 2 Minuten')
    return schedule.CancelJob
    
schedule.every().day.at("09:29").do(schedule_every_four_hours)
    
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```