# in python how to exit from a program using wait and schedule once schedule is complete

Tags: python, schedule

I'm trying to extend a solution so that the Pyton program ends after schedule is done working for a time period.

I am following the solution
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198116/how-to-schedule-job-with-a-particular-time-as-well-as-interval?rq=3](https://stackoverflow.com)

and I pasted the code for the specific solution I'm using here:

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt 

def job():
    now = dt.now()
    dt_string =  now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print ("I am working " ,dt_string )#your job function
 
def schedule_every_four_hours():
    job() #for the first job to run
 
    schedule.every(2).minutes.until("09:46").do(job)
    

    print(' 2 Minuten')
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().day.at("09:29").do(schedule_every_four_hours)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is that this will never exit. If I comment out the "while True", then it will exit, but scheduling code will never run because the program does exit. So how does write the code so that after running for a period of time the python program actually exits and cleans up nicely by itself. My intent is to add code that writes data to a file, so I want to be able to flush buffers and close the file cleanly as well as return a return code.

There is another  related question where it's recommended to use

```
  os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

But to me this seems to be an unclean programming way to end a program.
See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424532/how-to-schedule-python-script-to-exit-at-given-time](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Change `while True:` to `while not done:`, then have your scheduler thing set `done  = True`.  You'll need `global done` in the function.